# Seaborn Heatmap with column names on all axes of heatmap visualization instead of on just default x and y axes

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have some large heatmaps that I wanted to produce with the column names on both the top/right axis along with the default axis that the seaborn heatmap functionality already enables.

My current attempt is as follows. Note -- the current code is done with example random data.

```
size = len(data.columns)
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size, size))
sns.heatmap(data.corr().abs(), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt= '.2f',ax=ax)
ax3 = ax.twiny()
ax3.set_aspect("equal")
print(ax.get_xlim())
ax3.set_xlim([0,ax.get_xlim()[1]])
ax3.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax3.set_xticklabels(data.columns.tolist())
ax3.tick_params(top=True)
ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
```

This produces the following Result: [image: Heatmap Data]

If you look at the top axis, there exist ticks with similar labels. However you'll see a shift in the placement of ticks. I was wondering if there's a way to do this so that it exactly matches that of the bottom axis. I think the code should be similar to do so to repeat y axis on the right axis too.

Comment: Try to remove `ax3.set_aspect("equal")`, because in my minimal example it looks like this line is making the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add two additional axes with the correct labels. To get a good looking output I would suggest to move the colorbar below the figure because the y-axis-ticky and the colorbar will be plotted in the same area and this is not good looking.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(10), 'col2':range(10, 20), })

size = len(data.columns)
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size, size))
sns.heatmap(data.corr().abs(), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt= '.2f',ax=ax, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal'})

#ax3.set_aspect("equal")
ax3 = ax.twiny()
ax3.set_xlim([0, ax.get_xlim()[1]])
ax3.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax3.set_xticklabels(data.columns.tolist())

ax4 = ax.twinx()
ax4.set_ylim([ax.get_ylim()[0],0])
ax4.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax4.set_yticklabels(data.columns.tolist())
```

**Output**

[image: with axis on both sides]

---

**Comment to your old code**

I was creating a minimal example using the code you shared and I found out that without the line `ax3.set_aspect("equal")` the output looks better.

**Example Code**

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(10), 'col2':range(10, 20), })

size = len(data.columns)
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size, size))
sns.heatmap(data.corr().abs(), annot=True, linewidths=.5, fmt= '.2f',ax=ax)
ax3 = ax.twiny()
# ax3.set_aspect("equal") <-- this line was causing some problems

ax3.set_xlim([0,ax.get_xlim()[1]])
ax3.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks())
ax3.set_xticklabels(data.columns.tolist())
```

| **Output with the line** | **Output without the line** |
| --- | --- |
| [image: wrong behavior] | [image: wanted behavior] |